# DataTable to List<T> conversion

Tags: c#, datatable, generic-list

Is there any better way than the following?

Particularly, I want to replace `Activator` with something else.

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);

            List<T> list = new List<T>();

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                object[] args = new object[1];

                args[0] = dr;

                list.Add((T)Activator.CreateInstance(type, args));
            }

            return list;
        }
```

Comment: seems fine to me.. you'll need to instantiate your T somehow...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing I want to mention is that you probably don't need a list.  Odds are, an IEnumerable is enough.  Even if you do need a list, it's trivial to convert an IEnumerable to a list.

With that in mind, this code is a nice generic way to accomplish it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(DataTable dt, Func<DataRow, T> translator)
{
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
       yield return translator(dr);
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can see how re-usable this is. All you need to do is supply a function that knows how to convert an individual DataRow into your T type.  That function *might* use Activator, but it doesn't have to.  It might just use a normal constructor and set a few properties.

Comment: +1, using yield you'll call your translator just as you need your `IEnumerable<T> `items; if you're using some logic to abort your list processing then you'll save some processor cycles.

Comment: But the problem with this approach is, it is not backward compatible with .net 2.0.

Comment: You can do with .NET 2.0, you just have to use an anonymous delegate instead of a Func<DataRow,T> to perform the conversion. Or you can even just write it without the delegate and map to your resulting class type directly and just use new()

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see any way to improve this code - why do you want to avoid `Activator`?

One option you could explore would be to create some sort of interface like this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Initialize(DataRow dr);
}
```

And then implement this interface on any type that gets passed to this method.  Then you would constrain your generic type parameter like this:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt)
    where T : IFoo, new()
```

Then change the implementation of your method like this:

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt)
    where T : IFoo, new()
{
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        T t = new T();
        t.Initialize(dr);
        list.Add(t);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd add to Andrew's answer is if you go that route you can (sorta) avoid the Activator class by constraining the generic method with a new() constraint.

```
public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt)
    where T : IFoo, new()
{
    ...
    foreach ( ... ) {
       var foo = new T();
       foo.Initialize(dataRow);
       list.Add(foo);
    }
    ...
}
```

The reason I say "sorta" is because C# actually just compiles that into an Activator.CreateInstance call at compile-time anyway. But it looks much cleaner.

Comment: Doh, looks like Andrew just added that to his answer too.